# How to add client extensions in ClientHello message of TLS 1.2 handshake

Tags: c++, ssl, handshake, schannel

I am working on TLS 1.2 client. The client fails to establish security context with server. It is sending ClientHello with certain set of extensions. Then it receives multiple messages from server: `ServerHello`, `Certificate`, `Server Key Exchange`, `CertificateRequest` and `Server Hello Done`. After that client resets the connection with error code `unexpected_message`.

Chrome browser establishes security context with the same target host just fine. I see it is sending much more extensions in its `ClientHello` message.

How can I add extensions to my ClientHello message additionally to the ones inserted by default? Client is in C++, it uses Schannel to communicate with server, and multiple calls to the function `InitializeSecurityContext()` from `sspi.h` to establish security context.

Small sample of C++ code snipped is well appreciated, as well as any advices which may help me to understand what is wrong with the client.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: do you know the word "cipher"?

Comment: 21 ciphers sent in ClientHello. And server selects one of them. I see it in ServerHello message, it has mutual cipher selected.